# IntelliJ Idea. Хоткейевский эквивалент Ctrl+K+D  в Visual Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

В Visual Studio Ctrl+K+D - значит автоматически выровнять (если так можно сказать) отступы в коде.

Например, было:

```
class Logger { private void a(){
int x = 10;}
}
```

После Ctrl+K+D:

```
class Logger
{
   private void a() 
   {
      int x = 10;
   }
}
```

Т.е. получаем "красивое форматирование".
Есть ли эквивалент в IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ctrl+Alt+L](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reformat-code-dialog.html), настройки отступов берутся из [этих](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-style.html) настроек.